# Print jasper subreports one after another

Tags: jasper-reports

I am having two subreports in jasper

```
subreport1: containing list of food and beverage items
subreport2: containing list of bar items
```

I want generate a PDF  using Java, by printing two lists one after another,
but when I try this these lists are merged together like this:

```
fnbitem1
baritem1
fnbitem2
baritem2
fnbitem3
baritem3
```

but my required output is:

```
fnbitem1
fnbitem2
fnbitem3

baritem1
baritem2
baritem3
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Is it possible that your subreport elements overlap in your design?

Comment: Share the `.jrxml` contents.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the placement of each subreport is incorrect, you should create 2 detail group, `Detail1` and `Detail2`, you place `subreport1` in Detail1, and `subreport2` in Detail2

```
<detail>
    <band >
        <subreport>
             .....
        </subreport>   
    </band>

    <band >
        <subreport>
             .....
        </subreport>   
    </band>
</detail>
```